# Scraping Wikipedia Content from Picture of The Day

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am trying to scrape a certain type of Wikipedia page and want to generalize it enough so I can iterate my scraping over multiple pages. You may use this page as an example page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:POTD/2009-01-01

I would like to scrape the summary which is below the image; however, when I do it with the wikipedia module, I get an empty string. When I use Beautfiful Soup and try to navigate to where the summary is, I cannot figure out what to write that will always give me the summary text without using something like this:

> soup.find( style ='display: inline-block; margin-left: **4px**; width: **314px**; vertical-align: middle;')

Notice the bold values. Those change every time depending on the page. But the style text essentially stays the same for every other page. So somehow, I would like to grab the text under this name or perhaps there is a much easier way. I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Here is some code you can use to see what I am aiming for but hope to do it for multiple pages:

```
source = requests.get(f'https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:POTD/2009-01-01').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')   
summary = soup.find(class_ = 'content').find(style = 'display: inline-block; margin-left: 4px; width: 314px; vertical-align: middle;').text
print(summary)
```

Result:

A team of obstetricians perform a Caesarean section (commonly called a "C-section") in a modern hospital. The image shows the very first moment the mother glimpses her new-born child. This is a surgical procedure in which incisions are made through a mother's abdomen (laparotomy) and uterus (hysterotomy) to deliver one or more babies. It is usually performed when a vaginal delivery would put the baby's or mother's life or health at risk, although in recent times it has been also performed upon request for childbirths that would otherwise have been natural.Photo credit: Salim Fadhley
Archive – More featured pictures...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't target the tags by style attribute, that's too fragile. Better approach is using CSS selectors.

`#mw-content-text div:has(> a > img) + div` will select `<div>` under `id=mw-content-text` that comes immediately after `<div>` that contains the `<img>`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:POTD/2009-01-01'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.select('#mw-content-text div:has(> a > img) + div'):
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
A team of obstetricians perform a Caesarean section (commonly called a "C-section") in a modern hospital. The image shows the very first moment the mother glimpses her new-born child. This is a surgical procedure in which incisions are made through a mother's abdomen (laparotomy) and uterus (hysterotomy) to deliver one or more babies. It is usually performed when a vaginal delivery would put the baby's or mother's life or health at risk, although in recent times it has been also performed upon request for childbirths that would otherwise have been natural.Photo credit: Salim Fadhley
Archive – More featured pictures...
```

---

More about CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a for loop?